# Create nested dictionary dynamically from table in python

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models

I want to make a dynamic menu that has sub-menus from values stored in a database using TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

my model "menu" has this:

```
-short_name
-description
-url
-father(ForeignKey(self,null=True))
```

My entries could be like this:

```
PK| SHORT DESC    |DESCRIPTION     |URL       |MENU_PK(father)
1 | Home          |Fist Page       |home      |null
2 | Administration|Site SetUp      |admin     |null
3 | Users         |Users Admin     |users     |2
4 | Warehouses    |Warehouses Admin|warehouses|2
...
```

I want to create a dictionary like this:

```
{'menu':[
    {'name':'Home','url':reverse('home')},
    {'name':'Administration','url':reverse('admin'),'menu':[
          {'name':'Users','url':reverse('users')},
          {'name':'Warehouses','url':reverse('warehouses')},
    ]},
    {'name':'Products','url':reverse('products'),'menu':[
          {'name':'New Product','url':reverse('newProduct')},
          {'name':'Report','url':reverse('productReport')},
    ]},
    {'name':'Blog','url':reverse('blog')},
    ...
]}
```

And then I can make the dynamic menu in the template,
do you have any idea how to make this?

I have tried to make the dictionary like this:

```
menudb = Menu.objects.filter(perfil__usuario__username=request.user.username)
    if menudb.count()>0:
        menus = {menu:[]}
        for m in menudb:
            data = {}
            data["name"]=m.name
            data["url"]=reverse(m.url)
            if m.father is not None:
                subs = {menu:[]}
                for sub in m.father:
                    subm = {}
                    subm["name"] = sub.name
                    subm["url"] = reverse(sub.url)
                    subs["menu"].append(subm)
                data["menu"]=sub
            menus["menu"].append(data)
```

Comment: I have tried to make the JSON manually, with .append, but I cant find a way to include another dictionary when it has a Father Menu

Comment: Can you please post your code where you're creating the JSON?